# Using jQuery to replace text breaks images

Tags: jquery, replace, alt

I have a site where the registered trademark symbol "®" is used a lot. This symbol is rendered at the same size as the surrounding text. Since I need it to display smaller and superscripted, I am using jQuery to find all instances of "®" on a page and replace it with "`<span class="reg-mark">®</span>`". This way I can style the display of that character.

I am using the following code for the search and replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/®/g,'<span class=\"reg-mark\">®</span>');
        $('body').html(strNewString);
    });
</script>
```

This successfully replaces all instances of "®" so that I can style them the way I want.

However, it also replaces instances of "®" in the 'alt' attribute of  tags, which breaks the display of the images.

Is there a way I can accomplish this search and replace while skipping over attribute values?

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: You should be replacing it with &reg; since the registration mark symbol is part of the Windows 1251 charset, which is not compatible with a good chunk of the universe.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to loop through the elements you're interested in (div, p, etc.) that would contain the registered symbol rather than the entire body?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div, p, a, h1, h2, h3').filter(":contains('®')").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('®', '<span class="reg-mark">®</span>'));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iqonac/3/edit)**

Comment: where is the case where in alt ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir , this will not alter the ALT attribute, that is exactly what the OP asked for :) As you can see (if you inspect the `anchor alt` attr. - it is not altered)

Comment: what about that situation  ,  where its not in any element ? `<body>®` ?

Comment: Put a ® in the `<body>` and I'll kick your finger with my eye ;)

Comment: Thanks @RoyiNamir. I'll give that a try. And I promise all my ®'s are inside a text element, so please keep your eyes and fingers to yourself! :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It appears to have replaced only the first ® it encountered. I need to replace them all (except within attributes).

Comment: @PhilipJones : Royi ! = Roko ;)

Comment: @PhilipJones, just use my demo, define the tags you need to encounter the `(R)` and if you want you can add  `body, ` in the collection.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - Oops. Sorry about the mixup. I'm reading names from the wrong end of the comment! I have added the following code and it is replacing only the first occurrence of ®.  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('div, p, a, h1, h2, h3, th, td').filter(":contains('®')").each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace('®', '<span class="reg-mark">®</span>'));
  });
 });

Comment: Here is your demo with your code and it works flawlessly: http://jsbin.com/iqonac/5/edit . Are your elements generated dynamically?

Comment: Much of the page content is pulled dynamically from a database using PHP. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a RegExp that requires the ® to be between sharp brackets

e.G.: /(>[^<]*)®([^<]*<)/

Then you could concat part 1, the new insertion and part 3 to the new match.

This however matches only occurences that are in-between HTML-brackets. If you want to match text in attributes of any kind this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery not selector. Just have it "not" on the `<img>` tag for example. 
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var strNewString = $('body:not(img)').html().replace(/®/g,'<span class=\"reg-mark\">®</span>');
        $('body').html(strNewString);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var strNewString = $('body:not(img)').html().replace(/®/g,'<span class=\"reg-mark\">®</span>');
        $('body').html(strNewString);
    });
</script>
```

I think that will do it. It should find all "@" in the BODY, but skip any in IMG tags. There are also selectors that will let you focus on the ALT tag. e.g.:

```
$('img[alt="@"]')
```